# Laravel request firing twice with custom validation class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a weird problem with my Laravel application, whereby this code gets called twice once the validation rules kick in. I have abstracted validation logic into a separate class, but no matter how I consume the API (tried using Postman, and with jQuery) it still appears to run twice with the output looking like this:

```
called{"email":["The email has already been taken."],"country":["The country must be a number."]}called{"email":["The email has already been taken."],"country":["The country must be a number."]}
```

I am only expecting one JSON response. I'm tearing my hair out, tried on two different connections and can't seem to work out why the custom request is called twice. This is a new Laravel app, so there isn't much code to conflict with it.

```
 //Create User Request extends standard request. Handles Validation
  public function __construct(CreateUserRequest $request){
        $this->request = $request;
  }

  public function register()
  {
    try{

      $array = DB::transaction(function(){

            $email = $this->request->input('email');
            $password = $this->request->input('password');
            $companyName = $this->request->input('companyName');
            $userName = $this->request->input('name');
            $country = $this->request->input('country');

            $company = Company::create([
                'name' => $companyName,
                'active'=>true,
                'country_id'=>$country
            ]);

            $user = User::create([
                'company_id' => $company->id,
                'name'=>'admin',
                'email' => $email,
                'password' => $password,
                'active' =>true
            ]);

            if( !$company || !$user )
            {
                throw new \Exception('User not created for account');
            }

            return compact('company', 'user');
          });

        $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($array['user']);
        return Response::json(compact('token'));
    }
    catch( Exception $e )
    {
        return Response::json(['error' => $e->getMessage() ],  HttpResponse::HTTP_CONFLICT );
    }
  }
```

Then the validation custom Request..

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Response;
class CreateUserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function response(array $errors)
    {
      //  return Response::json(['errorg' => $errors ], 200 );
      echo('called');
    }
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
     return [
          'email' => 'required|unique:users',
          'password' => 'required',
          'companyName' => 'required',
          'name' => 'required',
          'country' => 'required|numeric'
      ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting.

Try to remove `CreateUserRequest $request` parameter from `__construct()` and add it to your `register()` method like this: `register(CreateUserRequest $request)`. And use your request by calling `$request` instead of `$this->request`.

Comment: Well, Request classes are made to handle request per method, not per controller.

I think that the first time Request Class was fired on __construct() and another one fired on real request to the method. Not sure actually.