# Laravel custom validation rules called twice

Tags: php, laravel, validation, recaptcha

I've got a problem with custom validation rule in my code.
I'm trying to validate recaptcha but after debugging i saw that validation is called twice.

I'm using Laravel 5.8 and i found this issue: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/25736 but I still have the problem.

Here is my code:

ReqistrationRequest.php

```php
public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            //some rules
            'captcha' => ['required', new Recaptcha]
            //some rules

        ];
        return $rules;
    }
```

Recaptcha.php

```php
class Recaptcha implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
      $client = new Client;
      $response = $client->post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
        [
          'form_params' =>
            [
              'secret' => env('GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET'),
              'response' => $value
            ]
        ]
      );
      $body = json_decode($response->getBody());
      Log::info('TEST RECAPTCHA BODY' . $response->getBody());
      return $body->success;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'MSG';
    }
}
```

After sending request my log file contains:

> [2019-10-30 10:30:28] local.INFO: TEST RECAPTCHA BODY{
>   "success": true,
>    "challenge_ts": "2019-10-30T10:19:18Z",
>    "hostname": "myhostname"
>   }
>   [2019-10-30 10:30:28] local.INFO: TEST RECAPTCHA BODY{
>    "success": false,
>    "error-codes": [
>      "timeout-or-duplicate"
>    ]
>   }

And response have code 422

Do you have any ideas why that happens?

---

EDIT:

I figured that I can check my captcha in Controller. Here is the code:

RegistrationRequest.php

```php
public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            //some rules
            'captcha' => 'required'
            //some rules

        ];
        return $rules;
    }
```

Recaptha.php

```php
class Recaptcha
{
    /**
     * @param  string  $captcha
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function isValid(string $captcha): bool
    {
      $client = new Client;
      $response = $client->post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
        [
          'form_params' =>
            [
              'secret' => env('GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET'),
              'response' => $captcha
            ]
        ]
      );
      $body = json_decode($response->getBody());
      return $body->success;
    }
}
```

MyController.php

```php
if (!RecaptchaCustomRule::isValid($request->get('captcha'))) {
        $this->response->error(trans('registration::app.captcha.required'), 422);
      }
```

And it works perfect for me.

Comment: May not be directly related to the question but why is there a curly bracket above ReqistrationRequest.php return?

Comment: My fault. I just paste the code incorrectly

Comment: see here : [laravel-request-firing-twice-with-custom-validation-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41128426/laravel-request-firing-twice-with-custom-validation-class)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel request firing twice with custom validation class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41128426/laravel-request-firing-twice-with-custom-validation-class)

Comment: I think it's not the problem because I'm passing my request to method in my controller not to __construct.